# C++ functions with Boolean arguments and SWIG python

Tags: c++, python, types, swig

Suppose I have the following SWIG interface file

```
%include "std_string.i"

%module Test %{
    std::string AmIABoolean(bool b)
    {
        return b ? "Sure" : "Yes I am";
    }
%}

std::string AmIABoolean(bool b);
```

When interfacing with this module from Python this works great when actually passing a boolean value.

```
>>> Test.AmIABoolean(False)
"Yes I am"
>>> Test.AmIABoolean(True)
'Sure'
```

But to my surprise (and dismay) SWIG accepts any argument for this particular test function

```
>>> Test.AmIABoolean([])
"Yes I am"
>>> Test.AmIABoolean("Free beer")
'Sure'
```

Is there a way to enforce a more strict type checking in the way SWIG matches a C++ to python method? Obviously this example is not very meaningful, but if I have a method with several overloads and one accepts a boolean argument, this means that SWIG always goes for that particular overload which accepts a boolean, which is highly undesirable.

Looking at the way SWIG checks for a boolean type in the interface file this behaviour is not too surprising

```
SWIGINTERN int
SWIG_AsVal_bool (PyObject *obj, bool *val)
{
  int r = PyObject_IsTrue(obj);
  if (r == -1)
    return SWIG_ERROR;
  if (val) *val = r ? true : false;
  return SWIG_OK;
}
```

as the Python documentation says the following about PyObject_IsTrue

> Returns 1 if the object o is considered to be true, and 0 otherwise.
>   This is equivalent to the Python expression not not o. On failure,
>   return -1.

and in the wonderful world of dynamic typing "Free beer" always evaluates to true

```
>>> not not "Free beer"
True
```

But surely SWIG must be able to differentiate between a value that ***is*** true and one that happens to evaluate to true. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is the normal python behaviour everywhere else. You rarely, if ever, call `isinstance(variable, bool)`, for example. Such is the dynamic nature of Python.

Comment: `!! "free beer"` also evaluates to true (1) in C++.

Comment: @Martijn, thanks I know. But don't you think an interface generator such as SWIG that bridges the gap between a dynamic and a statically typed language should account for these changes in idiom?

@David, touche! But `void f(bool b); f("Free beer");` will not compile though, and this is exactly what the SWIG interface allows when calling f from Python.

Comment: @user1556435: *...should account for these changes in idiom*. That's what SWIG is doing, it's adapting Python idiom to work with your interface.